# What is known about the coding sequence of Factor H in the human genome?

Tags: genetics, sequence-assembly

[Factor H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_H) is a protein coded in 20 domains.

My question is whether these domains form some kind of **repeat** cluster in the human genome. Basically, I'm interested in the coding sequence from an assembly point of view: Is the coding region fully resolved? Apparently there is only one copy of the gene per haplotype, but are coding domains maybe similar to each other or repetitive in themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in the WP article:

> The molecule is made up of 20 complement control protein (CCP) modules (also referred to as Short Consensus Repeats or sushi domains) connected to one another by short linkers (of between three and eight amino acid residues) and arranged in an extended head to tail fashion.

So in your terminology yes, it is a *repeat cluster*. Each of those 20 domains will be similar to the others, although not identical.

Answer (score 0):

The ensembl entry, which was easy to get to from the Wikipeda page, shows that the protein is one gene with 20 domains

http://uswest.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Transcript/ProteinSummary?db=core;g=ENSG00000000971;r=1:196651878-196747504;t=ENST00000367429

Comment: I don't see how this answer adds anything to what I already mention in the question. The question is whether those domains form a repeat cluster in the genome and whether the full sequence has been resolved in the human genome.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster your question said "a molecule made up of 20 proteins"; the answer says "one gene with 20 domains". Those are enormously different things.  If Factor H is a single protein and not 20 proteins, then obviously it forms a cluster (called a gene).  What makes you think it is formed by 20 proteins (a claim that isn't substantiated by your wikipedia link)?

Comment: The key word in my question is "repeat". Yes, it is one big protein and yes its domains are clustered. If you read my question carefully, you'll see that I mention that it is coded by a single gene. My question is whether these coding domains are "similar to each other or repetitive in themselves". Whether you'll call the parts proteins or not is not substantial to the question, but I'll change it just in case.